# Android Simple layout of an application

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to make an application that has `LinearLayout` on the top of screen and this one is showed for all the time the app is running.
Under this `LinearLayout` I want to have a content that changes. My idea is to make there many Layouts and change their visibility depending on what user does. Is it a good idea? Or should I use something else that is more efficient and user friendly?

Comment: try using fragments.. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Answer (score 3):

Multiple designs in a single layout file is not recommended. rather than that you can go for the fragmentation in android. otherwise you can create different layout files with the same top linear layout file and put your content below it.

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Make a `BaseActivity` that has this `LinearLayout` and other general LL. Now let the other activity extend this `BaseActivity` and you can play around with this "general LL" in ur sub-activities :)